# Recuperar Dados do Mysql

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, mysqli, tabela-banco-de-dados, backup

Desinstalei o mysql, não fiz backup do banco, mas fiz backup dos arquivos: ibdata1, ib_logfile0 e ib_logfile1.

O arquivo ibdata1 tem 17GB, no my.cnf o innodb_file_per_table=0.

Como faço para recuperar esses dados ? Existe algum software ou procedimento que faça com que eu tenha esses dados de volta?

Obs:Tenho o xampp instalado e pretendo testar com ele.

Comment: os dados do seu banco ficam dentro de uma pasta, são arquivos `.frm`, `.MYD`, `.MYI`. Esses arquivos que você salvou são apenas arquivos do próprio banco. Deveria ter salvo a pasta `Data` completa. A estrutura é: `...\Mysql\Data\\[minhaBaseDeDados]\`

Comment: Meu objetivo seria recuperar os dados do banco e não a estrutura das tabelas, mas obrigado Rovann.

Comment: mas os dados do banco, vão estar dentro dessas pastas, cada pasta para uma database, os arquivos externos são apenas do sistema mysql

Comment: Você pode tentar esse procedimento que o amigo recomendou:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54007/mysql-backup-from-ibdata1-ib-logfile1-ib-logfile0